# How to update a ABAP Hashed table

Tags: hashtable, updates, abap

How to update an ABAP Hased table?

What is the equivalent of the Java statement:

```
hashMap.put("myKey", "myValue");
```

in ABAP?

Comment: The usual table operators apply as well, with some (documented) restictions. What have you tried so far, what is the exact problem?

Comment: As  @vwegert said, you have to show some effort, like posting what you have tried. *Remember that a hashed table is also an internal table.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working example:**

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF LINE,
    COL1,
    COL2,
  END OF LINE.

DATA:   WA TYPE LINE,
      ITAB TYPE HASHED TABLE OF LINE WITH UNIQUE KEY COL1.

WA-COL1 = 'X'. INSERT WA INTO TABLE ITAB.
WA-COL1 = 'Y'. INSERT WA INTO TABLE ITAB.
WA-COL1 = 'Y'. INSERT WA INTO TABLE ITAB. "Not added
```

Comment: Thx for a complete code example with comment. I'll test it further - but accept already

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are only interested in the effect put() has on the content of hashMap and don't care about the value it returns, the equivalent would be:

```
INSERT VALUE #( KEY = 'myKey' VALUE = 'myValue' ) INTO TABLE hashMap.
```

With the difference that for an existing key the entry will not be updated but SY-SUBRC will be set to 4, so you'd have to do some extra work. Internal table hashMap needs to be defined as a HASHED TABLE WITH UNIQUE KEY KEY and a type that has at least the fields KEY and VALUE.

Also see: [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abapinsert_itab.htm)

Comment: Thx for the short explanation and link. This should help (therefore +1)